# Why are faces so low-dimensional? (i.e. why does the eigenface approach work so well?)

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

I (think I) understand PCA, but it still blows my mind that you can get such good reconstruction of the faces with only like 20 eigenface components. How is that possible?? Why should it be the case that faces lie more or less on a 20-dimensional hyperplane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because all the faces derive from the same genetic code, or "program", which evolution has established should look a certain way; a forward-looking pair of eyes, a centrally-placed nose with a pair of nostrils, etc. Maybe you should try running eigenfaces with all our primate cousins and see how many components you need?

If you're interested in pursuing this train of thought from a more analytical perspective look up the "manifold hypothesis".

Comment: +1. Or: run eigenfaces with [flies](https://www.google.com/search?q=fly+face&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=CNV8VNG-J4PtO9z2gegF&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1574&bih=900). Or with octopi. Or with skyscrapers, or beer bottles. That something is identifiable as a face (rather than as a beer bottle) already says that it shares a lot of features with other things we recognize as faces.

Comment: It's funny you mention beer bottles because I watched deep learning demo the other day that _did_ confuse them for humans. If you squint, they do look rather feminine from a distance :)

Comment: I will *not* tell my wife she looks like a beer bottle.